# Extra scroll with IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have the following website (and please excuse the language of the site, it's in Hebrew), and I apologize for posting a link here. I promise to replace the link with something generic as soon as the problem is fixed:

EDIT: original site replaced with this: `http://example.com`

For some reason, there's an extra scroll to the left with IE7.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: Its kind of unclear what you are trying to fix. Could you post a Window capture of the problem, and the related code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
html {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

I also noticed your horizontal scrool bar in IE is related to:

```
<ul id="nav1"></ul>
```

It has `position:absolute;` that is causing the additional horizontal scrool.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I noticed that as well. I'll try the overflow:auto method

Comment: I made a variation of your answer. Instead I did html { overflow-x: hidden; }...That solved it...